# Loading related data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a two table called `Post` and `Comments` where `Post` may contains many `Comments`. These are my model

```
public class Post
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostText { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
  }

public class Comment
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentTime { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Posts { get; set; }
  }
```

Now I want data Post data and its related comments. This is how I have implemented my service

```
public Post GetPostById(int id)
    {
      var result = _dataContext.Set<Post>().Include(p => p.Comments).ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationUsers).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
      return result;
    }
```

And this is how I have configured my mappings

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
      builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
      builder.Property(p => p.PostText).IsUnicode(true).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(9999);
      builder.Property(p => p.Title).IsUnicode(true).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
      builder.Property(p => p.PostDate).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now).IsRequired(true);
      builder.Property(p => p.Status).HasDefaultValue(true).IsRequired(true);

      builder.HasMany(p => p.Comments)
        .WithOne(p => p.Posts)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

      builder.HasOne(p => p.ApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(p => p.Posts);
    }
```

But this code doen't return me a comments. How can I achieve this approach
Thanks.

Comment: can you share your mappings? (onModelCreating)

Comment: @Simonare - Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, you need to have `public int PostId { get; set; }` in Comment Class

can you try with this line?

```
builder.HasMany(p => p.Comments)
    .WithOne(p => p.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PostId);
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

why dont you get results like this?

```
_dataContex.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments).ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationUsers).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```